# Python print statement prints nothing with a carriage return

Tags: python, command-line, carriage-return

I'm trying to write a simple tool that reads files from disc, does some image processing, and returns the result of the algorithm. Since the program can sometimes take awhile, I like to have a progress bar so I know where it is in the program. And since I don't like to clutter up my command line and I'm on a Unix platform, I wanted to use the '\r' character to print the progress bar on only one line.

But when I have this code here, it prints nothing.

```
# Files is a list with the filenames
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    print '\r%d / %d' % (i, len(files)),
    # Code that takes a long time
```

I have also tried:

```
print '\r', i, '/', len(files),
```

Now just to make sure this worked in python, I tried this:

```
heartbeat = 1
while True:
    print '\rHello, world', heartbeat,
    heartbeat += 1
```

This code works perfectly. What's going on? My understanding of carriage returns on Linux was that it would just move the line feed character to the beginning and then I could overwrite old text that was written previously, as long as I don't print a newline anywhere. This doesn't seem to be happening though.

Also, is there a better way to display a progress bar in a command line than what I'm current trying to do?

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print statement. It's possible that `print` isn't flushing the output until it writes a newline, which doesn't happen here.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Still not entirely sure why the hello world example worked. It didn't issue a line feed either. Maybe because the print statement was running enough that it auto-flushed the buffer after a certain number of characters?

Comment: Yes, it must have flushed the buffer when it became full.

Comment: Alternatively, one may use `sys.stderr` to print immediately to the screen. By default `stderr` is unbuffered.

Answer (score 2):

Handling of carriage returns in Linux differs greatly between terminal-emulators.

Normally, one would use terminal escape codes that would tell the terminal emulator to move the virtual "carriage" around the screen (think full-screen programs running over BBS lines). The ones I'm aware of are the VT100 escape codes:

`\e[A`: up
`\e[B`: down
`\e[C`: right
`\e[D`: left
`\e[1~`: home
`\e[4~`: end

Where `\e` is the escape character, `\x1b`.

Try replacing all `\r`'s with `\e[1~`

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925859/cygwin-bash-and-ansi-control-sequences)

Answer (score 2):

If your terminal is line-buffered, you may need a `sys.stdout.flush()` to see your printing if you don't issue a linefeed.